# Optimization the cost of fish tank

Tags: optimization

I am trying to minimize the cost of the fish tank. The cost of the tank is depending on the thickness of the tank.

- The shape of tank is a cylinder without a top.
- The tank is going to have a volume 250 gal.
- If the tank height is greater then 24 in. then the thickness has to
  be 1/2 in. If the height is less or equal to 24 in., then the thickness
  can be 3/8 in..
- Cost of 1/2 in. thick glass is 0.28 per sq. in..
- Cost of 3/8 in. thick glass is 0.17 per sq. in..

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If $r$ is the outer radius of the tank, $t$ is its thickness and $h$ is its height, the surface of the tank is
$$2\pi rh+\pi r^2$$
The volumen is known, so you can write
$$V=\pi (r-t)^2h$$
and solve this equation for $r$. You should express $V$ in cubic inches instead of gallons.

Substitute in the surface expression to build a function $S(h,t)$ which takes the height and the thickness and gives the surface.

Now define piecewise a function $f(h)$ that gives the cost:
$$f(h)=\begin{cases}
0.17\cdot S(h,3/8)\text{ if }h\le24\\
0.28\cdot S(h,1/2)\text{ if }h>24
\end{cases}$$

Differentiate $f$ to find its minimum. Note that the minimum could be at a discontinuity poit.